# Oracle SQL Migrate data from date range / period to months

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date, migration

I have some problems in migrating data from one table to another. Im using a Oracle 11 database. In my problem, one table states some values which are valid in a specific date range (start date and end date). The other table, to which the data should be migrated to, should state these values per month (MMYYY). So for a specific time frame (for example 01/01/2010 to 31/12/2010), the data should be stated per month (01/2010, 02/2010, ..., 31/2010). I was trying to create a suitable sql insert statement for this case but i was not successful in it.

---

Example:

Table 1 has the following attributes: ID (PK), START_DATE, END_DATE, VALUE

Table 2 has the following attributes: ID (PK), MONTH, YEAR, VALUE

---

Table 1:

- ID = 1, START_DATE = 01/01/2010, END_DATE = 31/12/2015, VALUE = 5
- ID = 2, START_DATE = 01/01/2012, END_DATE = 31/12/2013, VALUE = 10
- ID = 3, START_DATE = 01/01/2018, END_DATE = 31/12/2020, VALUE = 15

These entries should look like the following in the new table:

Table 2:

- ID = 1, MONTH = 01, YEAR = 2010, VALUE = 5
- ID = 1, MONTH = 02, YEAR = 2010, VALUE = 5
- ID = 1, MONTH = 03, YEAR = 2010, VALUE = 5
- ...
- ID = 1, MONTH = 12, YEAR = 2015, VALUE = 5
- ID = 2, MONTH = 01, YEAR = 2012, VALUE = 10
- ID = 2, MONTH = 02, YEAR = 2012, VALUE = 10
- ID = 2, MONTH = 03, YEAR = 2012, VALUE = 10
- ...
- ID = 2, MONTH = 12, YEAR = 2013, VALUE = 10
- ID = 3, MONTH = 01, YEAR = 2018, VALUE = 15
- ID = 3, MONTH = 02, YEAR = 2018, VALUE = 15
- ID = 3, MONTH = 03, YEAR = 2018, VALUE = 15
- ...
- ID = 3, MONTH = 12, YEAR = 2020, VALUE = 15

---

Is there a best practice way to do this? Or does anyone have an idea? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

convert your field using TO_DATE('mm/yyyy')
You can find more info here: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php